# ListView cache for different color filters is not working

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view

I'm using a listview that uses ViewHolder pattern and get advantage of caching mechanism. Here is a code snippet that I try to set one of my list item's background

```
if(drawable!=null)
    {
        if(this.backgroundBurnColor!=null && this.backgroundBurnColor.getValue()!=0)
        {
            Log.d("burncolor", this.backgroundBurnColor.getValue()+"");
            drawable.setColorFilter(this.backgroundBurnColor.getValue(), Mode.MULTIPLY);


        }else if(this.burnColorKey!=null)
        {
            Log.d("burncolor", this.Owner.getOwner().getColors().get(this.burnColorKey).getValue()+"");
            drawable.setColorFilter(this.Owner.getOwner().getColors().get(this.burnColorKey).getValue(), Mode.MULTIPLY);
        }else{
            drawable.setColorFilter(null);
        }
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
```

In this code the drawable is  for the same item type, but even if the same item type when I change drawable image it changes as I want. But changing color filter of the drawable changes every drawables filter in the list part appearing on screen. For example when I scroll down the list and a different color filter appears on the screen, then all drawables' color filters turn to the same filter, I need to get the seperate color filter for my each row. Any help? Thanks

Comment: post your complete `getView` code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For those who wonders about the answer,
There is a blog post by Romain Guy about drawable mutations in android : 
http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/

When drawables are referenced from the resources, only one instance of a Drawable initialized, so all references referring to the same object. for this  there is a  `mutate()` method for drawables

Instead of writing

```
 drawable.setColorFilter(null);
```

writing

```
 drawable.mutate().setColorFilter(null);
```

will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The color filter is set on a `Drawable`. So if you don't want two items to have the same color filter, you should have two separate `Drawable` objects for those two items.

Comment: so you say we don't have the same change to show drawables in cache with different color filters?

Comment: All items that need the same color filter can share the same cached `Drawable`. So you need the same number of `Drawable` objects as the number of different colors.